# What 2.8 BETA version still had all the tool LABELS on screen, and where can I get it?

Tags: interface

My 2.8 final release for Win7 64-bit ( with EEVEE compatible Quadro graphics )
only shows Tool labels when mouse-hovering over each tiny icon at a time.  I want to learn on a version that still has the WORD labels ( like all the previous versions ).  I still use 2.79 with a bunch of purchased addons.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "word labels"? Do you mean the Python tooltips?

Comment: rjg asked >>>Can you clarify what you mean by "word labels"? Do you mean the Python tooltips? <<<    .  .  .  Preferences has the checkbox option to 'Show Tooltips'.  For every version in the past 5 years, AND several (at least) months of 2.8 beta releases, the word label of the Tool was on the screen.  My 2.8 ONLY shows teenie tiny cryptic ICONS until I mouse-hover and WAIT over each one ( and that is only because I checked 'Show Tooltips' in Preferences ).  I want WORD LABELS ( like ALL previous versions ).

Comment: You HAVE NOT answered my question.  For many years, the Blender site had a Directory with previous versions.  This is hidden now.  You can go through the past year of BlenderArtist and see MANY screenshots of pre-release 2.8 showing the labels.  I want the most recent Beta that STILL HAD them before they were REMOVED.

Comment: You can expand the toolbar, as mentioned in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/tool_system.html#toolbar): "Expand the Toolbar to show icons on two columns instead of one or even more to show icons with titles."

Comment: @Sanne you're right, my bad. I totally missed that. Can you add that as an answer?

Comment: The definition of the labels happens in the `space_toolsystem_toolbar.py` where the class `_defs_view3d_generic` contains the functions for each tool that return a dictionary with its properties, like for instance the label. The `ToolSelectPanelHelper` in `space_toolsystem_common.py` is responsible for the actual layout, including the single and multi-column layout and drawing the labels. The label is displayed if the width scale exceeds 120.0 and `show_text` is set to `true`. `draw_cls` will then display the label next to the icon.

Comment: BTW the older releases of Blender are still available just like before (it does not include alphas and betas though): https://download.blender.org/release/

Comment: Thanks much, Sanne and rjg.

Answer (score 3):

You can expand the toolbar, as mentioned in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/tool_system.html#toolbar): "Expand the Toolbar to show icons on two columns instead of one or even more to show icons with titles."

[image]